# pyodbc.Error: ('08S01', '[08S01] [unixODBC][FreeTDS][SQL Server]Unable to connect

Tags: python, sql-server, freetds

I need help with the next code.

I have a function that calls data_client and passes the Client B, C and D in a for loop. So I receive these clients on data_client and process them one by one. But when I insert the data (on SQL SERVER) I only can insert one or two clients and not the three of them.
For example I have to comment

```
#insert(i, j, k, l) or #insert(e, f, g, h) or #insert(a, b, c, d)
```

and the process works fine, but if the three functions are without comments the script throws this error:

```
con = pyodbc.connect("DRIVER={FreeTDS};SERVER=server;UID=usr;PWD=pass;DATABASE=DB_A")
```

pyodbc.Error: ('08S01', '[08S01] [unixODBC][FreeTDS][SQL Server]Unable to connect: Adaptive Server is unavailable or does not exist (20009) (SQLDriverConnectW)')

---

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# coding: utf-8
import pyodbc

def data_client(client, a1, a2):
    if client == 'B':
        insert(a, b, c, d)

    elif client == 'C':
        insert(e, f, g, h)

    elif client == 'D':
        insert(i, j, k, l)

def insert(arg1, arg2, arg3, arg4):
    con = pyodbc.connect("DRIVER={FreeTDS};SERVER=server;UID=usr;PWD=pass;DATABASE=DB_A")
    cur = con.cursor()
    try:
        cur.execute("""INSERT INTO [DB_A].[dbo].[tb_A] ([col_a] ,[col_b] ,[col_c],[col_d]) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?);""", [arg1, arg2, arg3, arg4.encode('utf-8')])
        con.commit()
    except pyodbc.IntegrityError, e:
        print 'error: ', e 
        #continue
    except pyodbc.InternalError, f:
        print 'intern error: ', f
        cur.execute("rollback;")
    cur.close()
    con.close()
```

I have to mention that:

Client B has around 1700 rows

Client C has around 5300 rows

Client D has around 700 rows

So I dont know if the error is because the amount of rows that I'm trying to insert or maybe a timeout problem or just another error.

Thanks in advance for your help!!